# What's the solution of this optimization problem, $\mathop{\arg\min} \|X+A\|_F^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, normed-spaces

Consider the following optimization problem
$$\mathop{\arg\min}_{X\text{ is positive semi-definite}} \|X+A\|_F^2$$
where $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is symmetric and $\|\cdot\|_F^2$ is the Frobenius norm.

I am wondering what's the solution $X$ of the above problem and how to derive the solution. The only thing I know so far is that it seems to be a convex optimization problem...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Let $H=\frac12(A+A^T)$ and $K=\frac12(A-A^T)$. By orthogonally diagonalising $H$, we may assume that
$$
H=\pmatrix{-D_1&0\\ 0&D_3}\ \text{ and }\ X=\pmatrix{X_1&X_2^T\\ X_2&X_3}
$$
where $D_1$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix and $D_3$ is a positive diagonal matrix. Since $X$ is positive semidefinite, so are $X_1$ and $X_3$. Therefore $X_3+D_3\succeq D_3\succeq0$ in positive semidefinite partial ordering, and
$$
\|X_3+D_3\|_F^2=\sum_i\lambda_i(X_3+D_3)^2\ge\sum_i\lambda_i(D_3)^2=\|D_3\|_F^2.
$$
It follows that
\begin{aligned}
\|X+A\|_F^2
&=\|X+H\|_F^2+\|K\|_F^2\\
&\ge\|X+H\|_F^2+\|K\|_F^2\\
&=\|X_1-D_1\|_F^2+\|X_3+D_3\|_F^2+\|D_1X_2^T\|_F^2+\|D_3X_2\|_F^2+\|K\|_F^2\\
&\ge\|D_3\|_F^2+\|K\|_F^2.
\end{aligned}
Clearly, $\|X+H\|_F^2=\|D_3\|_F^2$ when $X=\pmatrix{D_1&0\\ 0&0}$. Therefore this $X$ is the global minimiser. In terms of $H$, this means
$$
X=\frac{(H^2)^{1/2}-H}{2}.
$$
(Note: since $H$ is not necessarily positive semidefinite, $(H^2)^{1/2}$ in general is not equal to $H$.)

Comment: The  [matrix sign function](https://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/fm/OT104HighamChapter5.pdf) is defined such that 
$$(A^2)^{1/2} = A\cdot{\rm sign}(A)$$
Since $A$ is posited to be symmetric
$$H={\rm sym}(A) = A$$
Therefore this solution can be reformulated as
$$X=\frac{1}{2}\Big(A\cdot{\rm sign}(A)-A\Big)$$

Comment: The OP assumed that $A$ is symmetric, so this answer could be greatly simplified.