# Frobenius norm: completing squares and minimizing

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, completing-the-square

I would like to minimize the following quantity:

$Q = \left\lVert{X - C}\right\rVert^2_F + a\left\lVert{X - I}\right\rVert^2_F$

Where $X\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is unknown, $C\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is a known positive semi-definite and symmetric matrix, $I$ is the identity matrix, $a\in\mathbb R^+$ and $\left\lVert\cdot\right\rVert_F$ is the Frobenius norm. There is also some constraint on $X$, but for simplicity let's assume that it is only needed to be positive semi-definite. If I could somehow complete the squares on $Q$ then I could you use [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3761263/whats-the-solution-of-this-optimization-problem-mathop-arg-min-xa-f2?noredirect=1&lq=1) to solve my problem.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Addendum to user1551

Find the gradient and set it to zero, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial X} = 2(X - C) + a 2(X - I) = 0 \Longrightarrow X = \frac{C + a I}{a+1}.
\end{align}
The solution is exactly the same as user1551's solution.

---

p.s.: there are several posts that explain how to compute gradient of Frobenius norm.
For instance, say $f:= \|X\|_F^2 = \operatorname{tr}(X^T X)\equiv X:X$ (double colon to denote Frobenius product). Then, compute differential followed by the gradient. So, $df = dX:X + X:dX = 2X:dX \Longrightarrow \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} = 2X$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While it explains more clearly than user1551's answer how to find the global minimiser it doesn't provide a formula suitable for working with constraints so I am a bit hesitant to accept it.

Comment: @cgss If you solve a problem, and the unconstrained solution satisfies your constraints, then you have also solved the constrained problem. This is often the quickest way to solve a constrained problem, since unconstrained techniques are simple and direct.

Comment: @greg I agree with that. The thing is that as I said in the question, the constraint was simplified. The actual constraint is that X minus a diagonal matrix is positive semidefinite.  So I need something of the form of user1551's answer to manipulate my constraints.

Answer (score 2):

The objective function is equal to $(a+1)\left\|X-\frac{C+aI}{a+1}\right\|_F^2+\text{constant}$. Hence the unique global minimiser is $X=\frac{C+aI}{a+1}$. As $C\succeq0$ and $a\ge0$, $X$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Could you please explain it with more details?